# recharts ReferenceLine in BarChart showing on a left side instead of the middle

Tags: recharts

Since I didn't get an answer on recharts github, I was wondering if anyone here could help out.

What I'm trying to do is to use ReferenceLine and a ReferenceDot to show 'today' on a xaxis in a Barchart. The ReferenceDot works fine, it's positioned in the middle of a Bar. Sadly, that's not the case with the ReferenceLine, which is positioned on the side of a Bar.

Does anyone know how to influence it? Any idea maybe how to write a custom component that could work?

[image: Image explaining my problem]

Comment: Did you get any answer about this behavior? I'm having the same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is also discussed on github.
https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/1521

As I suggested in the above post, temporary solution is adding `scale="point"` to `<XAxis>`.

For example,
`<XAxis dataKey="name" scale="point" />`

But I think this is just a quick patch.
Root cause may be at scale function handling of `<XAxis />` and/or `<ReferenceLine />`.